# Recording location history, location movement is not consistent & jumped around

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, geolocation, location

I'm new to android programming and currently involved in gps tracking development. I managed to create location listener and start the tracking and record the movement into database on server. What i'm concern is that the coordinate seems jump from one location to another. I can see the main pattern of movement, but get wonder what would made that jump. Tracked device is using network as provider (FINE & COARSE) and I'm suspecting the marker jump is due to the device seeing nearby BTS. Any suggestion to avoid/eliminate this? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the necessary code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

For acurate positions you need GPS provider. To avoid jumps, move with a speed a bit higher than walking speed.
Having a clean movement path for low speeds is difficult to achieve.